# Always display value in highcharts column chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am not exactly new to highcharts, but I am not exactly a "power user" either.

I have these charts on a security report that will almost invariably always have at least 1 column that has no value displayed because the value is too low, compared to the others.

The design requirement is that these do not have tool tips, just the data being displayed.

Maybe I am being thick, but when I think i see the answer I try it and it doesn't work... for example I have tried setting the "min" attribute on the x axis etc, but no luck. Is this doable? I assume if it is, I am putting the attribute in the wrong place.

Here is an example, look at column one code sample is in there... but it is below as well

**JSFiddle Link** : http://jsfiddle.net/ur58nae5/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            backgroundColor: null,
            style: {
            fontFamily: 'helvetica, arial'
            }
        },
        colors:['#F5A623'],
        credits: false,
        title: {
            text: 'Attacks by Risk Score'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Number of malicious IPs seen in this period based on maximum risk score'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            title: {
            text: "Risk Score"
            },
            labels: {
                rotation: 0,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '11px',
                    fontFamily: 'helvetica, arial, Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Number of IP Addresses'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'IPS',
            data: [
                ['1', 21],
                ['2', 109],
                ['3', 112],
                ['4', 125],
                ['5', 106],
                ['6', 112],
                ['7', 143],
                ['8', 207],
                ['9', 386],
                ['10', 908]

            ],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                rotation: -90,
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'right',
                y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
                style: {
                    fontSize: '10px',
                    fontFamily: 'helvetica, arial, sans-serif',
                    textShadow: false,
                    fontWeight: 'normal'

                }
            }
        }]
    });

});
```

Comment: so you want datalabels for all columns? and tooltip disabled for columns with values below a certain threshold? did in understand that right?

Comment: Not understanding what you're asking for at all. Can you be more specific about exactly what it is you want, and what is happening instead?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, your problem is that sometimes the columns are too small to display the dataLabels.  You have a couple of options:
You can use a `logarithmic` scale to make the data differences less pronounced.
http://jsfiddle.net/ur58nae5/1/

```
    yAxis: {
        type:'logarithmic',
        title: {
            text: 'Number of IP Addresses'
        }
    },
```

Or you can format points that are smaller than some threshold to move the label outside the column

```
series: [{
    name: 'IPS',
    data: [
        {x:1, y:21, dataLabels: { color:'#000', y:-15}},
        ['2', 109],
        ['3', 112],
        ['4', 125],
        ['5', 106],
        ['6', 112],
        ['7', 143],
        ['8', 207],
        ['9', 386],
        ['10', 908]

    ],
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        rotation: -90,
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        align: 'right',
        y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
        style: {
            fontSize: '10px',
            fontFamily: 'helvetica, arial, sans-serif',
            textShadow: false,
            fontWeight: 'normal'

        }
    }
}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ur58nae5/2/
http://jsfiddle.net/ur58nae5/3/

Comment: Your second solution is nicely done (3rd fiddle especially). Using a log axis for this purpose is an almost universally terrible idea, however, as it distorts the data enough in many cases to be nearly meaningless for purposes of comparison between the bars.